# Getting Error while creating file

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

```
public void saveByteArrayToFile(Context context){
        Log.v(TAG, "Save byte array to file");
        switch(mType){
            case ChatMessage.AUDIO_MESSAGE:
                filePath = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName;
                break;
            case ChatMessage.VIDEO_MESSAGE:
                filePath = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName;
                break;
            case ChatMessage.FILE_MESSAGE:
                filePath = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName;
                break;
            case ChatMessage.DRAWING_MESSAGE:
                filePath = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName;
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Mera path"+filePath);
        File file = new File(filePath);

        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());

            fos.write(byteArray);
            fos.close();
            Log.v(TAG, "Write byte array to file DONE !");
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Write byte array to file FAILED !");
        }
    }
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/...
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I am getting this error while creating file.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to write to that path?

Answer (score 0):

So, file exists. Then this happens:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
```

Now it doesn't exist, so you cannot use:

```
file.getPath();
```

Instead, use this:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already done this, but you will need to declare that your app will be writing to external storage in your manifest (and if targeting apk version 23+, you will also need to request that the user accepts these permissions before they are granted to your app).

Add this line inside the application tag in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If targeting SDK version 23+ you need to request runtime permissions, as detailed at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html